# Create REST API with Neo4J and Django

Tags: django, api, rest, neo4j, neo4django

I am trying to create a REST API with Neo4j and Django in the backend.

The problem is that even when I have Django models using Neo4Django , I can't use frameworks like Tastypie or Piston that normally serialize models into JSON (or XML).

Sorry if my question is confusing or not clear, I am newbie to webservices.

Thanks for you help

---

EDIT: So I started with Tastypie and followed the tutorial on this page `http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html`. I am looking for displaying the Neo4j JSON response in the browser, but when I try to access to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/node/?format=json` I get this error instead:

```
{"error_message": "'NoneType' object is not callable", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 217, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 459, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 491, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1298, in get_list\n    base_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 718, in build_bundle\n    obj = self._meta.object_class()\n\nTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable\n"}
```

Here is my code :

api.py file:

```
class NodeResource (ModelResource): #it doesn't work with Resource neither
    class meta:
        queryset= Node.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'node'
```

urls.py file:

```
node_resource= NodeResource()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(node_resource.urls)),
```

models.py file :

```
class Node(models.NodeModel):
    p1 = models.StringProperty()
    p2 = models.StringProperty()
```

Comment: "I can't use frameworks like Tastypie or Piston that normally serialize models into JSON (or XML)". When you say you can't use these frameworks, why not? What problem are you encountering? (I'm not familiar with Neo4J, but your question looks like it needs more detail.)

Comment: The models I created are based on the Neo4Django framework which is relying on the neo4j rest client for python. 
So what I am normally getting when a query is made to the db, is a JSON ! (see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html)

Comment: Why not just directly make calls to the Neo4j rest api? It seems to me that you're trying to act as a wrapper for calls you're making to that api anyway (correct me if I'm wrong), so you should just try returning the JSON you get from neo4j.

Comment: Yes, some queries to neo4j are made through the REST API. 
Actually, I was thinking about those frameworks because AFAIK, they allow to create structured REST APIs (aren't they ? ), so I will not have to do the work myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django-Tastypie allows to create REST APIs with NoSQL databases as well as mentioned in http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html.

The principle is to use `tastypie.resources.Resource` and not `tastypie.resources.ModelResource` which is SPECIFIC to RDBMS, then main functions must be redefined in order to provide a JSON with the desired parameters.

So I took the example given in the link, modified it and used Neo4j REST Client for Python to get an instance of the db and perform requests, and it worked like a charm.

Thanks for all your responses :)

Comment: Hi! Have you got any example of that? I'm exactly in the same situation than you :)

Comment: (note: I succeed to make it work with ModelResource but filters failed)

Comment: Hi, I'll try to post full answer asap  
(sorry for this late response, was a bit busy these days :) )

Comment: @Pirhoo I posted a full answer below (sorry for the lateness )

Answer (score 6):

I would advise steering away from passing Neo4j REST API responses directly through your application. Not only would you not be in control of the structure of these data formats as they evolve and deprecate (which they do) but you would be exposing unnecessary internals of your database layer.

Besides Neo4Django, you have a couple of other options you might want to consider. [Neomodel](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/neomodel.html) is another model layer designed for Django and intended to act like the built-in ORM; you also have the option of the raw [OGM layer](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/ogm.html) provided by py2neo which may help but isn't Django-specific.

It's worth remembering that Django and its plug-ins have been designed around a traditional RDBMS, not a graph database, so none of these solutions will be perfect. Whatever you choose, you're likely to have to carry out a fair amount of transformation work to create your application's API.

Comment: Concerning the JSON returned by the Neo4j REST API, i was thinking about retrieving only the part containing data.
It is also true that using frameworks to create models similar to those existing in Django's ORM, allows to structure the application. But it becomes a hindrance when we want to perform big queries (performance of Rest API compared to Core API), so i am intending to use both of them in my application (through server plugins).

Comment: My experience is that Neo4django is much better supported than Neomodel. The lead developer is very helpful. Just my 2c.

Comment: Neomodel is a much younger project but both Matt (neo4django) and Rob (neomodel) are great guys and in my experience, both very helpful and committed to the Neo4j community. Python + Neo4j = Win :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [recent](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/pull/186) [contributions](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/pull/191), Neo4django now supports Tastypie out of the box! I'd love to know what you think if you try it out.

EDIT:

I've just run through the tastypie tutorial, and [posted a gist](https://gist.github.com/mhluongo/5789513) with the resulting example. I noticed nested resources are a little funny, but otherwise it works great. I'm pretty sure the gents who contributed the patches enabling this support also know how to take care of nested resources- I'll ask them to speak up.

EDIT:

As long as relationships are specified in the `ModelResource`, they work great. If anyone would like to see examples, let me know.

Comment: Ha thanks, but the credit absolutely goes to Lukas (@lutoma) and @d9puces on GitHub :)

Comment: It is indeed really nice, but for some reason it crashed for me.
Maybe it needs some update?

Answer (score 2):

Well my answer was a bit vague so I'm gonna post how a solved the problem with some code:

Assume that I want to create an airport resource with some attributes. I will structure this in 3 different files (for readability reasons).

- First : `airport.py`

This file will contain all the resource attributes and a constructor too :

```
from models import *

class Airport(object):

    def __init__ (self, iata, icao, name, asciiName, geonamesId, wikipedia, id, latitude, longitude):
        self.icao = icao
        self.iata = iata
        self.name = name
        self.geonamesId = geonamesId
        self.wikipedia = wikipedia
        self.id = id
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.asciiName = asciiName
```

This file will be used in order to create resources.

---

- Then the second file : `AirportResource.py`:
  This file will contain the resource attributes and some basic methods depending on which request we want our resource to handle.

  ```
  class AirportResource(Resource):

      iata = fields.CharField(attribute='iata')
      icao = fields.CharField(attribute='icao')
      name = fields.CharField(attribute='name')
      asciiName = fields.CharField(attribute='asciiName')
      latitude = fields.FloatField(attribute='latitude')
      longitude = fields.FloatField(attribute='longitude')
      wikipedia= fields.CharField(attribute='wikipedia')
      geonamesId= fields.IntegerField(attribute='geonamesId')

      class Meta:
          resource_name = 'airport'
          object_class = Airport 
          allowed_methods=['get', 'put'] 
          collection_name = 'airports'
          detail_uri_name = 'id'

      def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
          kwargs = {}
          if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
              kwargs['id'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.id
          else:
              kwargs['id'] = bundle_or_obj.id

          return kwargs
  ```

As mentioned in the docs, if we want to create an API that handle CREATE, GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests, we must override/implement the following methods :

`def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs)` : to GET a list of objects

`def obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs)` : to GET an individual object

`def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs)` to create an object (CREATE method)

`def obj_update(self, bundle, **kwargs)` to update an object (PUT method)

`def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs)` to delete an object (DELETE method)

(see http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html)

Normally, in `ModelResource` all those methods are defined and implemented, so they can be used directly without any difficulty. But in this case, they should be customized according to what we want to do.

Let's see an example of implementing `obj_get_list` and `obj_get` :

For obj_get_list:

In `ModelResource`, the data is FIRSTLY fetched from the database, then it could be FILTERED according to the filter declared in META class ( see http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html). But I didn't wish to implement such behavior (get everything then filter), so I made a query to Neo4j given the query string parameters:

```
def obj_get_list(self,bundle, **kwargs):
    data=[]
    params= []
    for key in bundle.request.GET.iterkeys():
        params.append(key)
        if "search" in params :
            query= bundle.request.GET['search']
            try:
                results = manager.searchAirport(query) 
                data = createAirportResources(results)
            except Exception as e:
                raise NotFound(e)
            else:
                raise BadRequest("Non valid URL")
    return data
```

and for obj_get:

```
def obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    id= kwargs['id'] 
    try :
        airportNode = manager.getAirportNode(id)
        airport = createAirportResources([airportNode])
        return airport[0]
    except Exception as e : 
        raise NotFound(e)
```

and finally a generic function that takes as parameter a list of nodes and returns a list of Airport objects:

```
def createAirportResources(nodes):
    data= []
    for node in nodes:
        iata = node.properties['iata']
        icao = node.properties['icao']
        name = node.properties['name']       
        asciiName = node.properties['asciiName']
        geonamesId = node.properties['geonamesId']
        wikipedia = node.properties['wikipedia']
        id = node.id
        latitude = node.properties['latitude']
        longitude = node.properties['longitude']
        airport = Airport(iata, icao, name, asciiName, geonamesId, wikipedia, id, latitude, longitude)
        data.append(airport)
    return data
```

---

- Now the third `manager.py` : which is in charge of making queries to the database and returning results :

First of all, I get an instance of the database using `neo4j rest client` framework :

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import *
gdb= GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
```

then the function which gets an airport node :

```
def getAirportNode(id):
    if(getNodeType(id) == type):
        n= gdb.nodes.get(id)
        return n
    else:
        raise Exception("This airport doesn't exist in the database")
```

and the one to perform search  (I am using a server plugin, see Neo4j docs for more details):

```
def searchAirport(query):
    airports= gdb.extensions.Search.search(query=query.strip(), searchType='airports', max=6)
    if len(airports) == 0:
        raise Exception('No airports match your query')
    else:
        return results
```

Hope this will help :)