# Graph DB with Django?

Tags: django, neo4j

I have not come across many people who have used a Graph DB(such as a Neo4j) with Django. Even though there exist ORMs such as Neo4Django, I am not too happy with these solutions as they are potentially buggy and have very late development cycle. What do you suggests are best solutions?

Comment: what do you mean by late development cycle and "potentially buggy" ?

Comment: Buggy - https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues?state=open there are many open fundamental issues and
Late dev cycle because current solution is not compatible with neo4j 2.x and Django 1.6+ and there is no dev pipeline

Answer (score 2):

As of today, `neo4django`'s latest commit is in July 2014. There seems to be [bulbflow](http://bulbflow.com/overview/) which mentions that it can be used from django. Its github link on their homepage is a broken URL. The only project I found linking bulbflow to django is https://github.com/theonion/django-bulbs , but it has a deprecation note to a broken URL. I just filed [issue #338](https://github.com/theonion/django-bulbs/issues/338) requesting if they can provide a fixed link, and the developer clarified that it has been converted into a private repository.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16922734/4126114) sheds some light and points mainly at [py2neo](http://py2neo.org/2.0/). In the same SO question, there is another answer stating that django was designed with RDBMS in mind.

For alternatives to django as a web framework with neo4j as backend, [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723159/which-web-application-framework-is-highly-integrated-with-neo4j?answertab=active#tab-top) seems to be quite rich with options.

Funny enough, more search through duckduckgo.com led me to [this blog post](https://medium.com/@amhopkins/my-new-development-stack-using-python-graphql-and-neo4j-the-brewmasters-guide-to-the-internet-87e3879009c4) which is like a hello world example of using neo4j. It mentions [neomodel](http://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (last commit 19 days ago), which links to [django-neomodel](https://github.com/robinedwards/django-neomodel) (last commit 6 months ago).

Answer (score 0):

For integrating Neo4j with Django, use Django's ORM for PostgreSQL and Neo4j's official Python driver (py2neo) for graph data. Write custom synchronization code between them for better control and reliability.